# How do I call a another sql file based on if a condition is true?

Tags: sql, oracle

The code I have used is listed below. but it throws the ORA-00972: identifier is too long

```
Declare

n number(2);

BEGIN

    n := 10;


    if(n > 0) then

         @'C:\giddo.sql';

    end if;

END;

/
```

The Giddo.sql consists of the following code

```
SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON PREFORMAT OFF ENTMAP ON HEAD "<TITLE>Reports</TITLE> 

<STYLE type='text/css'>tr{background-color:#E4EAF7;font-weight: Bold;color:#BLACK;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri;font-size: 14px;text-align:left;caption-side:top;align:left;} td{border-color:white;padding:0;background:#FFFFFF;font-family:Calibri;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;color: BLACK;text-decoration: none;text-align:left} BODY {padding:1;background:#ffffff;font-weight: Bold;color:#004fa3;text-decoration:none;font-family:Calibri;font-size: 15px;text-align:left; margin:20 0 0 20;} th{align:left;text-align:left;color:black}</STYLE>" TABLE "cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1 border=1 width=100%"

set linesize 10000
SET PAGESIZE 10000 
set feedback off
set serveroutput on;


spool C:\Popot.html append ;


 BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('<-------------------------------------------This is a test line--------------------------------------------------->');
   END;
 /



spool off

SET markup HTML off


/
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the sql statement within `giddo.sql` for your issue.

Oracle imposes a limit of 128 characters for both the table and a column name, and it seems that you are exceeding this limit.

Aliasing the column will reduce the column name.

Example:

```
SQL> select distinct office_id "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit" from test;
select distinct office_id "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit" from test
                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00972: identifier is too long
```

I created a file `ttt.sql` with content:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('<-------------------------------------------This is a test line--------------------------------------------------->');
 END;
```

And executed it as:

```
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> DECLARE
  2     n   NUMBER (2);
BEGIN
  3     n := 10;

  4  
   IF (n > 0)
  5     THEN
  6        @ttt.sql;
  7     --dbms_output.put_line('Hi');
  8   
   END IF;
END; 
 /
<-------------------------------------------This is a test
line--------------------------------------------------->

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Yes, if you can do it.

Comment: I tried your script without `<STYLE type` and it worked. Can you check if you remove then it works or not.

Comment: do you mean you tried it out without the entire css.... could please post a snapshot of the output